# How to determine if a Directory/Folder has been changed

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

I have a folder with the following structure

```
Parent/
    Child1/
        GrandChild1/
             File1.txt
```

I need to query Parent folder and find out if Child1 has changed.

Changed = A new file was add/update/deleted.

The Child1 folder DateModified is not updated. Only the GrandChild1 date modified was updated when changes occurs. I am trying to avoid going to the file level to determine if the rootparent has changed. since there will be many folders and sub folder.  I just need to know if Child1 has changed.

I do not want to use FileSystemWatcher, since I am running this as a scheduled job and not watching it LIVE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User FileSystemWatcher. Remember to enable raising events since it is a common mistake (watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = true;).

The FileSystemWatcher may prove not to be optimal from a performance perspective. If that is an issue for you, you might implement a [CRC](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net) check with a Timer to check for changes of the files and folders you are interested in.

Essentially, what I would do is to [generate a CRC32 hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988665/hashing-a-tree-structure) for the entire folder I am watching (and save it away into variable A) and when I decide it is time to check for changes, you simply calculate a new CRC32 hash for the same folder (into variable B). You then compare A with B and if they don´t match, something has changed. Really not that difficult.

Reference:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/netfxbcl/thread/b7612249-eb32-4005-9d6b-7f291c218326
- http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net
- http://marknelson.us/1992/05/01/file-verification-using-crc-2/

Comment: Certainly the simplest solution. But FileSystemWatcher can have [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes) reliability issues.

Comment: I have used it a couple of times before and never had any problems. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I am runnng a schedule job and cannot use the FileSystemWatcher. Since I am not running live.

Comment: Ok, see my edit. Consider implementing a CRC solution to check for changes!

Comment: @Marcus, it's no longer relavant to the OP's question, but this question addresses some of the issues devs have had with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the file system watcher?
You can monitor local drives for changes from a given path, and then if necessary, ignore or process the fact they changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) Class for this.

Alternatively, if you would rather schedule a Task to run, Weekly, for example, you might want to have a look at: http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/ and http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2004/08/Interfacing-the-Windows-Task-Scheduler.aspx

And here's a link to the  [Windows Task Schedular API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way without having to watch it? I want to run this check once a week and not to have it monitored

Comment: You could programmatically schedule a Windows Task from within your application, that Watches a directory, or sub-directory at a given date and time (or, Weekly). See my answer for further details.