# How to check if a non binary tree is a subtree of another

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm working with trees and i need to know how to check if  if a non binary tree is a subtree of another.

These trees could have n nodes and n levels, and the children's order is not important. I just to know if the tree is a subtree of another

The problem for me is how to do a recursion and compare both tree at the same time with a recursion.

for that i create an exemple to demonstrate what i want to do.

I know the roots of both tree and i;m trying to do that in ruby on rails, but for know i justa want to know a pseudo code or the logic.

[image]
[image]

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use ideas from hash tree or [Merkle Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree):

> a hash tree or Merkle tree is a tree in which every non-leaf node is
>   labelled with the hash of the labels of its children nodes. Hash trees
>   are useful because they allow efficient and secure verification of the
>   contents of large data structures.

See also [Hashing a Tree Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988665/hashing-a-tree-structure)