# Memory allocation for a tree and its subtree

Tags: memory, tree, binary-tree, memory-address

In linux system.

If I have two binary trees, tree A has millions of nodes, while tree B has only a few hundred nodes.

I want to check if B is a subtree of A.

One solution I am thinking is, say, A uses 50Mb of the memory, and the addresses are contiguous, while B uses 1Kb. If B is part of A, the addresses of B would be a subset of A's addresses (I guess?).

So can I use tree A’s memory address range and B’s memory address range to determine if B is a subtree of A?

UPDATE:
I think if we are using static memory allocation, and there is one node that refers to the same pointer as the root of B refers to, probably when we find that node, we can determine B is a subtree of A.

Comment: I dont get the question. Maybe some clarification.

Comment: @user3344003Just modified, please tell me if it is still ambiguous to you :p

Comment: Are A and B in the address space of a single process?

Comment: @user3344003 If they are in different processes, then there is no need to do this check I think? So let's assume they are in the same process.

Comment: It's not safe to assume anything about the memory addresses of the contents of these trees. Each node that was provided by the memory allocator could have come from anywhere, such a previously deleted bit of memory from elsewhere. I think you need to walk tree A looking for B, then once you find it, walk both trees in lockstep and confirm that every child in B has the same child in A.

Comment: @RonKuper What I am saying is to define some constraints to see if the 'memory address' strategy possible under the certain circumstance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the memory addresses of *A* and *B* to check for the equality of *A* and *B*.

An alternative is to generate a hash of the *B* tree.  Then do a depth first traversal of *A*, generating the hash of the subtrees of *A*.  If the hash of a subtree of *A* matches the hash of *B*, then verify that *B* matches that particular *A* subtree.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988665/hashing-a-tree-structure) for generating a hash from a tree.

Comment: Never thought about generating a hash, good thought! Thank you!